# Error while trying to install Wordcloud in python

Tags: python, pip, pycharm

I am using python 3.8 on Pycharm IDE. 
When I try to install the wordcloud package, I get the following error.

[image]

I can see that the pip command failed to load wheel. I reinstalled wheel but this did not solve the problem. Below is the list of all the packages installed.

[image]

I am not sure what exactly I am missing. Your help is much appreciated.

Thank you so much

Comment: try upgrade pip first, and then install your package

Comment: I did. This is the latest pip version

Comment: You could read this issue: https://github.com/amueller/word_cloud/issues/105. They have some probable solutions.

Comment: Do you have a C compiler installed?